# getting specific video frame

Tags: c#, .net, directshow, directshow.net

I have been browsing around here (stack overflow) attempting to find a stable way to get images (an array of pixels) out of video files in general. In C# .NET I have found:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/ExtractVideoFrames.aspx

Which is almost exactly what I am looking for but I keep getting this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.DexterLib,
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load
a program with an incorrect format.
```

Everything compiles fine but when run the .net runtime does not like 'Interop.DexterLib', I have double checked that it is in the bin with the exe and the project has them linked properly and compiles fine.

After some googleing the error seems to revolve around x86 .dlls and running them in x64 bit operating systems. To negate this they recommended building for x86, VS2010 does not have this option as they replaced it with "Any CPU"? Is this the problem? and is there any good way to fix it?

Is there a better way to get video frames in C#, I have looked at DirectShow.Net and for the life of me I cannot understand what is going on within direct show. I have yet to find a solution as simple as this (if it would work).

My final objective is to be able to get frames from 2 video files in byte arrays... modify them, and then save them back to a new video. First things first is getting the video into memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong with your Visual Studio. My 2010 has these options:
[image]

Comment: This could be the problem, Possibly could it be because this project was "upgraded" from VS2008? I do not have the "Platform Target:" on my "Build" Page anywhere. Under platform the only option i get is "Active (Any CPU) ? (I attempted to do: http://preview.tinyurl.com/3rn3l5o ) But that had no effect.

Comment: Start a new DLL project in studio 2010 then use it from you project.

Comment: After completing the above step, i was able to open the "Configuration Manager..." from the drop down at the top of visual studio. Created a new "Active Solution Configuration" and then it allowed me to change to x86 or x64. Then the compiler bugged me about /unsafe not being used. After checking "Allow Unsafe Code" it compiles and now (probably due to me selecting bad video files) i keep getting the error: No video stream was found. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `corflags` to make your 64 bit assembly compatible with x86 platform

[Corflags description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The MediaDet from that article is part of DirectShow. Just use DirectShow.NET and your linking problems will go away. If you need to save modified frames to another video, you'll have to build a DirectShow graph, using just MediaDet will not help you.